# Why do the Taliban commit atrocities on Afghan civilians?

Tags: terrorism, afghanistan, taliban

I've been following the recent developments in Afghanistan and have been flummoxed on the issue of - why Taliban is continuously bombing its own people incessantly? I have read that it is because they want to exert leverage on the ongoing negotiations between US and Taliban, but I am failing to understand how can you expect to govern the same people you don't shy away from bombing recklessly? how can people readily assume to be governed by people who view citizens with no humility and regard for their fellow inhabitants  political mileage? I am sure there are lot of deep layers/forces underpinning this but I am unable to get comprehend them in a way that helps me understand the political, social, cultural and all other dimension to this issue. My limited understanding tells me that terrorists often have a cause for which they fight. I want to understand that. Here in India, media rarely have such in depth and nuance coverage of issues.

Comment: Interesting thing to add is an amount of civilians killed with US drones - it overwhelms those killed by Taliban last year.

Comment: The American bomb the villages when gives Taliban more support, and they use it as a propaganda. And the Taliban bomb the cities for the revenge. But at the end it's the civilians who suffer. If you ask mostly afghans they consider Taliban and US evil.

Comment: @user2501323: Upon reading it, it seemed to me your comment could not possibly be true, but to my great surprise, it seems the numbers are in the correct ballpark: casual wiki search [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_drone_strikes_in_Afghanistan) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilian_casualties_in_the_war_in_Afghanistan_(2001%E2%80%93present)#Civilian_and_overall_casualties_(2018))

Comment: I am assuming you are looking for something more than the Taliban are a religious death cult?  But that's the long and short of it.

Comment: "but I am failing to understand how can you expect to govern the same people you don't shy away from bombing recklessly"

By bombing them some more of course. The Taliban don't necessarily want to rule by consent, they are fine ruling by fear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Taliban mostly bomb big cities they argue that the people in big cities are silence about the West invasion, and they deserve to be killed. For example Kabul, the capital gets bombed now almost daily. The second reason is the Taliban don't want to win the heart and mind of people they want to rule by fear and force which is what they did when they were in power.

Answer (score 4):

Your question begins with incorrect assumptions. The Taliban does not bomb people randomly. They target places and things that are linked with the US occupation. This includes the central government set up with the help of the US, which they consider to be an American puppet.

This is all part of normal guerilla warfare.

Comment: ok tell me this what had bombing School, market, with american pupets? killing innocent children women dose noting to do with US occupation

Comment: -1 "They target places and things that are linked with the US occupation" or schools or shias or, well, you get the picture.

Comment: no i dont get the picture how a children school is concted to US ocupation. Taliban are scums who kill innocent people just like us

Comment: The Taliban are a bunch of religious fanatics.  Of course they commit atrocities against civilians, bomb cultural and economic centers, and vandalize historical sites.

Comment: "US occupation" sounds like you're repeating their line. Also "places and things" sounds like you think they don't target people deliberately, just infrastructure.